# Flex AS3 - unable to send POST data

Tags: php, actionscript-3, apache-flex, post, air

This would be idea of AS code (Flex/AIR platform):

```
protected function login_btn_login_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
{

    var urlLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
    var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest(config.domain+'/oms/request/user/login');

    Alert.show(login_inp_username.text) // OK!
    var requestVars:URLVariables = new URLVariables();
    requestVars.username = login_inp_username.text;
    requestVars.password = login_inp_password.text;

    request.data = requestVars;
    request.method = URLRequestMethod.POST
    urlLoader.load(request);


    urlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,login_evt_complete);
    urlLoader.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR,login_evt_ioerror);


}

protected function login_evt_ioerror(e:Event):void {
        Alert.show('IO Error: Check connection')
}

protected function login_evt_complete(e:Event):void {
        //  var response:XML = e.currentTarget;
        var response:XML = new XML(e.target.data);
        Alert.show(response)
}
```

And PHP:

```
<?php

    echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <result>result:'.$_POST['username'].'</result>
';

?>
```

This is all I get

[image]

(Problem is that with PHP I can't read POST data... or they are not send):

---

Any point to solution would be apreciated.

Comment: try Alert.show(response.toXMLString())

Comment: @f-a Then I get this `<result>result:</result>`

Comment: what is the value of login_inp_username.text;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed this line

```
var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest(config.domain+'/oms/request/user/login');
```

to this

```
var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest(config.domain+'/oms/request/user/login/index.php');
```

and it worked...

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the URLLoader.dataFormat to TEXT

```
urlLoader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.TEXT;
```

Also not sure if it matters but try setting the url to login.php.

Other than that your code seems correct.

Answer (score 0):

try see all the data with

```
dump($varName)
```